# can't decode file bitmapfactory

Tags: android, url, bitmap, android-imageview, bitmapfactory

i have to create an application using android which have facility to see user image into circularimageview for circularimageview i am using com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView library and use bitmap to display image from URL but i can't display images in imageview it shows some error

```
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 277K, 5% free 7693K/8044K, paused 2ms, total    2ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 747K, 9% free 8469K/9288K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:  /http:/hennasilks.com/jijo/informe/profile_images/galimg2017-02- 16T11:16:02.403+0530178.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
I/System.out: jijonull
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /http:/hennasilks.com/jijo/informe/profile_images/galimg2017-02-16T11:16:02.403+0530178.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
I/System.out: jijonull
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /http:/hennasilks.com/jijo/informe/profile_images/galimg2017-02-16T11:16:02.403+0530178.jpeg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 I/System.out: jijonull
 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 325K, 7% free 9612K/10284K, paused 5ms, total 6ms
 I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 11.409MB for 2048012-byte allocation
  D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 6% free 11606K/12288K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
 D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 34K, 6% free 11604K/12288K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
 I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 29.683MB for 19170444-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 3% free 30320K/31012K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
 V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
V/FA: onUnbind called for intent. action: com.google.android.gms.measurement.START
V/FA: Local AppMeasurementService is shutting down
```

here is my code to use display image

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 4;
String profurl="http://hennasilks.com/jijo/informe/profile_images/galimg2017-02-16T11:16:02.403+0530178.jpeg";
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(profurl,options);
System.out.println("jijo"+bitmap);
int height = bitmap.getHeight(), width = bitmap.getWidth();
if (height > 1280 && width > 960)
{

    Bitmap imgbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(profurl);
    holder.prof.setImageURI(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(imgbitmap)));
    holder.prof.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else {
    holder.prof.setImageURI(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(bitmap)));
    holder.prof.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

please help me to find a solution thanks in advance

Comment: use picasso or glide

Comment: @DeepakKumar give example

Comment: if you want to load image via URL then you should use picasso or glide because its very simple to use and light weight library

Comment: please give me example

Answer (score 1):

Use picasso library or 1st download the image in local storage and use local path for decode file

```
    String profurl="http://hennasilks.com/jijo/informe/profile_images/galimg2017-02-16T11:16:02.403+0530178.jpeg";

    Picasso.with(yourActiviy.this).load(pic_url).error(R.drawable.profile_pic).into(iv__pic);
```

add this in build.gradle

```
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: can i load using bitmap

Comment: Yes but 1st download image and store into local storage and then set

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download the image and then convert it into bitmap.
alternatively you can use glide to load image.
if you are using eclips edt then download glide.jar file and put it into your libs folder or if you are using studio then put this sigle line your gradle file compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0' . 
after that use this single line to show image.

```
Glide.with(context).load(image url).into(your image view).
```